# UI glitches in pre-lollipop devices

Tags: android

Hi everyone i am developing an android app using support libraries for backward compatibility
i only applied SeekBar and Options Menu to check if everything is going well
when i ran it on Marshmallow device it works perfect
but when i ran it on Kitkat , some shadows appear around these view objects

i spend last 15hours searching all over the internet but all in vain
if anyone knows what this problem is called
or what the solution is
i will be very thankful

Screenshot 1[image: []

Screenshot 2[image]

Comment: Thankss a lottt friend
it solved my problem :) :)
finally a relief, now i can continue my project
thanks again soo much

Comment: No problem. If you can, please mark that as helpful, so others can see that your problem is solved. Cheers!